# find the invalid email records from the dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe in pandas. In that dataframe to find the email records like is there any special characters,valid.com mails and dell.com mails in that email column.

Here is the DataFrame:

```
Email                    FirstName        LastNAme

jocovich@valid.com           A                 B
sindhu@gmail.com             c                 D
jagan@dell.com               E                 F  
sri;reddy@valid.com          G                 H
bsred:reddy@outlook.com      I                 J
kap?l@gmail.com              K                 L
rohi\t@hotmail.com           M                 N 
yuvi/@msdn.com               O                 P
sid.darth@live.com           Q                 R
bharagvi@gm\ail.com          S                 T
krish@mailer.com;            U                 V
```

My required output is:

```
Email                  FirstName            LastName

jocovich@valid.com           A                 B
jagan@dell.com               E                 F
sri;reddy@valid.com          G                 H
bsred:reddy@outlook.com      I                 J
kap?l@gmail.com              K                 L
rohi\t@hotmail.com           M                 N 
yuvi/@msdn.com               O                 P
sid.darth@live.com           Q                 R
bharagvi@gm\ail.com          S                 T
```

I want to display the invalid email records from Dataframe and delete records from the dataframe and to write the records into newsheet.

Here is code snippet:

```py
df.loc[df['Email'].str.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_\/;:?]+@[^@\/;"?]+\.[^@]+')]

with pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\users\desktop\\newfile.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='invalid emails', index=False)
    writer.save()

writer.close()
```

above code snippet is not working. can you please provide the best regex code snippet for above required output.

Comment: why are these invalid jocovich@valid.com
jagan@dell.com

Comment: i don't need whatever emails i mentioned

Comment: these two seem to me as valid emails

Comment: i know but i don't need those emails also

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do something like this. 
You can tweak the list `chars` as per your needs.

```
chars=['\?', '\:','\;','\/',r'\\','valid.com','dell.com' ]
df[df['Email'].str.contains('|'.join(chars), case=False)]
```

**Output**

```
                 Email  FirstName   LastNAme
0   jocovich@valid.com          A   B
2   jagan@dell.com              E   F
3   sri;reddy@valid.com         G   H
4   bsred:reddy@outlook.com     I   J
5   kap?l@gmail.com             K   L
6   rohi\t@hotmail.com          M   N
7   yuvi/@msdn.com              O   P
9   bharagvi@gm\ail.com         S   T
10  krish@mailer.com;           U   V
```